# Setting Property To Button Publicly

Tags: c#, properties

```
private string connectionName;

public string ConnectionName
{
    get { return connectionName; }
    set { connectionName = tbConnect.Text; }
}
```

After I enter value to Connect TextBox, ConnectionName property is returning null.

If I set my property as below, then I won't be able to use the property value publicly in my other classes.

```
public string ConnectionName
        {
            get { return connectionName; }
            set { connectionName = value; }
        }

private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectionName= tbConnect.Text;
        }
```

What would be the proper way to set ConnectionName property to use publicly?

Comment: why would you be using a textbox to enter the connection, can you show what the connection looks like ..? also create `Auto Property` for example `public string ConnectionName {get; set;};`

Comment: I am trying to create an windows form app to connect to a db. I have other text boxes to collect info to create connection string. I wanna pass all these textbox values in public properties. 
For example:
string myConnectionString= "user id=" + UserID+ ";password=" + Password + ";data source=" + "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)" + "(HOST=" + HostName + ")(PORT=" + Port + "))(CONNECT_DATA=" + "(SERVICE_NAME=" + Service + ")))";

Comment: you need to read up on how to create and use connection string.. using textboxes is not a good way to go.. what if you have a typo.. please read up on how to configure a connection string inside App.Config file .. tons of examples online.. your approach is a flawed one at best

Comment: This is just a mock tool for demonstration purposes. But I will look into AppConfig files. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: horrible approach.. if you want to show the connectionstring broken down into it's parts in readonly textboxes do that after you construct a valid connection sting I would highly suggest you get inline with today's standards in regards to connection strings and using the Configuration file

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will take it into consideration. Since I am still a student, I will try to get inline with today's standards.

Comment: this will help you to get ahead of the game.. also look up `C# Basics Tutorials` and focus on the `properties` section to understand get; set; vs Auto Properties this will make your life much easier..

Comment: not a problem at least you are giving it a try..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160247/discussion-between-jacktheripper-and-methodman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After I enter value to Connect TextBox, `ConnectionName` property is
>   returning null.

Yeah, because you never set `connectionName`, but you are returning it in the `ConnectionName` getter. The following would create a property that sets/gets the value of the textbox:

```
public string ConnectionName
{
    get { return tbConnect.Text; }
    set { tbConnect.Text = value; }
}
```

---

> If I set my property as below, then I won't be able to use the
>   property value publicly in my other classes.

No, that's not true, since `ConnectionName` is declared as `public`.

Comment: Thank you so much Adrian. I was just confused how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to implement this property would be either

```
private string connectionName;

public string ConnectionName
{
    get { return connectionName; }
    set { connectionName = value }
}
```

Or

```
public string ConnectionName { get; set; }
```

If you have a form where the user enters the connection name into a textbox, you should add an "OK", "Save," or "Apply" button to the form, and code its click handler like this:

```
protected void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myObject.ConnectionName = tbConnect.Text;
}
```

... where myObject is a reference to an instance of the class that has the ConnectionName property.